# np.append. Необходимо добавить в конец матрицы столбец

Tags: python, numpy

Две матрицы. Столбец одной добавляем к другой матрице.

```
a=np.array([[2,4,6],[8,10,12]])
a=a.transpose()
b=np.array([[1,3,5],[7,9,11]])
b=b.transpose()
a=np.append(a,b[:,0],axis=1)
```

Что не так?

> ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions

Comment: приведите пример выходной матрицы пожалуйста. Сейчас непонятно чего вы хотите добиться...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите присоединить первый столбец `b` к `a`:

```
In [11]: np.column_stack((a, b[:, 0]))
Out[11]:
array([[ 2,  8,  1],
       [ 4, 10,  3],
       [ 6, 12,  5]])
```

"плоский" (`1D`) вариант:

```
In [15]: np.append(a.ravel(), b[:, 0])
Out[15]: array([ 2,  8,  4, 10,  6, 12,  1,  3,  5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Если `axis` явно указано, то [`np.append`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.append.html) требует, чтобы входные массивы имели бы одинаковую размерность (2D в этом случае). Можно добавить новую размерность (из строки сделать столбец), используя [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis):

```
>>> b[:,0]
array([3, 3, 3])
>>> b[:,0,np.newaxis]
array([[3],
       [3],
       [3]])
>>> np.append(a, b[:,0,np.newaxis], axis=1)
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

где `a`, `b` массивы:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([(1, 2)]*3)
>>> b = np.array([(3, 4)]*3)
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
>>> b
array([[3, 4],
       [3, 4],
       [3, 4]])
```

Можно ещё добавить столбец из `b` в `a`, используя [`np.c_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html):

```
>>> np.c_[a, b[:,0]]
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```